# Application onCreate() NOT getting called every time

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a very important initialization to do when the app starts. I found the best way to do is to put that code inside onCreate() of the class which extends Application class.

```
class ApplicationDemo extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate(){
 super.onCreate();
 Log.d("LOG", "Inside onCreate()");
}

}
```

**The Problem**

I do not find the log statement to be executed every time the app is run. Like I start the app for the first time, get the log statement, then close the app and start again from the launcher. No, the log statement doesn't come.

What is the problem? How can I ensure a particular code is run every time my app is run and before anything else is performed?

Comment: When you put your app to background, it is not automatically killed and does not require re-creation when an activity is launched. So, what do you mean by "every time my app is run" - every time the application is created or every time an activity is resumed (hint: `onResume()`)?

Comment: Are you 'force closing' the app?

Comment: @laalto This simply means that "every time an user opens the app from the launcher icon". The onCreate() of the Application class is not getting called everytime.

Comment: @Karim This is probably not needed as the user is pressing the back button to close the app and start again from the launcher.

Comment: @Aritra pressing the back button closes/finishes the Activity, but not the Application. Try force closing the app from the "Recent apps" menu, and see if the Application's onCreate is getting called.

Comment: @Karim That would not be a solution as a normal user will not be clearing it from the "Recents" every time. They can just close the app and re-open again.

Comment: you forgot to put `@Override` before `public void onCreate()` (ie. `@Override public void onCreate()`)

Comment: did u get solution?

Answer (score 4):

**My guess** is that you truly have open your application **just once**.

I'm pretty sure that, after you *closed* your application, it truly just goes into the background, waiting to be put in the foreground again. (It does not get created again, you only reuse something you already have created.)

Try making sure you actually [killed the process of your application](http://www.wikihow.com/Close-Apps-on-Android) before re-opening it; to make sure you actually closed & reopen it, and not just do a simple background-foreground thingy.

Comment: That's a good explanation. So what would be the best way to run a piece of code every time the app starts (before any other code is run)?

Comment: you may add that code in the first screen that starts in the app, Like Splash Screen.

Comment: @Aritra you can create abstract class ProjectBaseActivity (extending Activity), run the code in its onResume and inherit all your other activities from it.

Comment: @simekadam An elaborate answer would be helpful.

Comment: @Aritra Simekadam is right, you'll have to check onresume() if you want when your app is called into the foreground again.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an Android activity lifecycle problem.
I've included a link about pausing and resuming an activity

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

It looks like when you are exiting the app, your activity is being paused. Likewise when you re enter the app, if the process is still running, the activity is getting resumed rather than recreated.

From here, you can either move the code to the onResume() or you can leave it in onCreate() but make sure that exiting the app kills the process. that could be done by putting

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

in any path that directs the user to the home screen (onBackPressed(), exit buttons, etc.)

for starting, try putting a Log statement in onResume and watch where the two get called.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you usually do not 'close' an application, but rather suspend it.
So, when you run it again, it just pops back.
To ensure your app is closed, open the list of running application, find your one and force stop it.

Answer (score 0):

An application or an activity can exist even if it's UI is not displaying. The `onCreate()` callback is only called when the object is created anew.

> This simply means that "every time an user opens the app from the launcher icon".

Then you should be putting the code in the `onResume()` callback of your launcher activity declared in the manifest. You can make the launcher activity a thin activity that only does this once-per-activation init and then launches the actual main activity.

Sure, there can be prior code run, such as `onCreate()` of the `Application` and `onCreate()` of the `Activity` so it won't always be the first thing to run, but it will be guaranteed to run every time you launch from the menu.

Comment: Yes, I know about that solution actually. But I cannot put that code in onResume of the launcher activity as that activity will come in the flow of the application many times and that code will run again and again. But I want that code to run only once.

Comment: "But I want that code to run only once" conflicts with the "every time an user opens the app from the launcher icon" requirement. Only once per what?

Comment: That piece of code should run only once every time the user opens the app from the launcher before any thing else is performed.

Comment: You can make the launcher activity a thin activity that only does this once-per-activation init and then launches the actual main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from bellow code for `Kotlin`:

```
override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level)
    when (level) {
        ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN -> {
            /*
               Release any UI objects that currently hold memory.

               "release your UI resources" is actually about things like caches.
               You usually don't have to worry about managing views or UI components because the OS
               already does that, and that's why there are all those callbacks for creating, starting,
               pausing, stopping and destroying an activity.
               The user interface has moved to the background.
            */
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_MODERATE,
        ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW,
        ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL -> {
            /*
               Release any memory that your app doesn't need to run.

               The device is running low on memory while the app is running.
               The event raised indicates the severity of the memory-related event.
               If the event is TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL, then the system will
               begin killing background processes.
            */
        }
        ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND,
        ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE,
        ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE -> {
            /*
               Release as much memory as the process can.
               The app is on the LRU list and the system is running low on memory.
               The event raised indicates where the app sits within the LRU list.
               If the event is TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE, the process will be one of
               the first to be terminated.
            */
        }

    }
}
```

And bellow code for `Java`:

```
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {

        // Determine which lifecycle or system event was raised.
        switch (level) {

            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN:

                /*
                   Release any UI objects that currently hold memory.

                   "release your UI resources" is actually about things like caches. 
                   You usually don't have to worry about managing views or UI components because the OS 
                   already does that, and that's why there are all those callbacks for creating, starting, 
                   pausing, stopping and destroying an activity.
                   The user interface has moved to the background.
                */
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_MODERATE:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL:

                /*
                   Release any memory that your app doesn't need to run.

                   The device is running low on memory while the app is running.
                   The event raised indicates the severity of the memory-related event.
                   If the event is TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL, then the system will
                   begin killing background processes.
                */

                break;

            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE:

                /*
                   Release as much memory as the process can.
                   The app is on the LRU list and the system is running low on memory.
                   The event raised indicates where the app sits within the LRU list.
                   If the event is TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE, the process will be one of
                   the first to be terminated.
                */

                break;

            default:
                /*
                  Release any non-critical data structures.
                  The app received an unrecognized memory level value
                  from the system. Treat this as a generic low-memory message.
                */
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should in AndroidManifest.xml in tag "application" set field android:name=".ApplicationDemo"

**UPD**
author edited question with my assertions.

Comment: These are all done in the real application. This seriously can no the reason of the problem.

Comment: Maybe class application should be public?

Answer (score -1):

On my phone even if I close an app it'll keep running in the background until you close from there manually.

You can use

```
onResume() {}
```

To run something every time the Activity gets called again.

Comment: onResume gets called everytime the an activity is foreground